# Group by in Access 2010 is taking extremely long

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2010, query-performance

I want to know if there is any logical mistake or any particular reason why a query in Ms Acess is taking very long when using group by command.

```
SELECT Futuro_v1.AÑO, Futuro_v1.MES,
Futuro_v1.Seg, 
Futuro_v1.CAR, 
Futuro_v1.Ent,
SUM(MIDT_Futuro_v1.P) AS P
FROM Futuro_v1
WHERE (Futuro_v1.CAR="X") AND MIDT_Futuro_v1.RUT="L"
GROUP BY AÑO, MES, SEG, CAR,  Ent
UNION ALL SELECT Cierre_v1.AÑO, Cierre_v1.MES,
Cierre_v1.Seg,
Cierre_v1.CAR, 
Cierre_v1.Ent,
SUM(Cierre_v1.P) AS P
FROM Cierre_v1
WHERE (Cierre_v1.CARRIER="X") AND Cierre_v1.RUT="L"
GROUP BY AÑO, MES, SEG, CAR, Ent;
```

If I exclude the "group by" command then I have a lot of rows (approx 900000) which I don't want. When I run this query with the "group by" I have the result wanted, and approx 74000 rows as result. However it takes very long approx 20 min to run the query.

Comment: You have SUM, so you need the group by. Do you have any index on your table?

Comment: Correct, if I delete the sum and do not use the group by then the query is very fast. I do not have any index in my tables. Thank you very much.

Comment: so try adding index on one or more fields you have in GROUP BY. start creating index on ANO. if it did not help add MES to index and so on...